# How can I get Riak to store images or binary data?

Tags: json, binary, riak

Can Riak be used to store images or binary data? It seems to only be able to store JSON documents, is this a correct assumption?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Riak can store arbitrary data. The jiak interface expects JSON with a certain "schema" however.

Answer (score 3):

As z8000 said, Riak can store any data you like.  If you're using the Erlang interface, just set the value of the riak_object to whatever you want to store.

If you're using HTTP, point your client at the "raw" interface: http://hg.basho.com/riak/src/tip/doc/raw-http-howto.txt  It allows you to store data and serve it with whatever content type you like.